# How to fix Joomla 1.5 website

Tags: web, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I had a very old website with Joomla 1.5 and I was about to upgrade it to the latest version. In the mean time, I tried to install the com_akeeba-3.4.3-core extension (to take backup) which left my website down. Now, I can not access both the admin and user pages.

I looked at the database but I couldn't find the component there. What should I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `which left my website down` << please explain in more detail?

Comment: After installing the extension, the page went blank. And, now both the admin and user pages return blank [white] page.

Comment: Delete all references to akeeba backup, the framework, component and plugins. The remove all references to it in the database. Once done, transfer your site **without** using Akeeba Backup

Comment: Thanks but I checked my database tables (e.g. component), there is no such reference and I doubt if the component is correctly installed. btw, the problem happened when installing the extension. I didn't even take the backup. Is there anything i can reset on Configration file or some where?

Comment: The blank page is usually caused by php fatal error, change your configuration file to show all errors and see what it says.

Comment: Thank you faridiv, I enabled the error reporting and there was an error in the file folder.php which is under libraries/joomla/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you faridiv, I enabled the error reporting and there was an error in the file folder.php which is under libraries/joomla/filesystem. And, now I can view my website.